# What is the adjoint of the depolarizing channel?

Tags: quantum-operation, density-matrix, depolarizing-channel

Consider the single qubit depolarizing noise channel given by

$$\Phi(\rho) = \frac{\lambda}{d} \mathbb{I}  + (1- \lambda) \rho.$$

What might be the adjoint $\Phi^{*}(\cdot)$ of this channel? In particular, I am trying to find how the adjoint acts on standard basis states $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 1|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** $\Phi^*=\Phi$.

If quantum channel $\Psi:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$ has a Kraus representation $\Psi(X)=\sum_iK_iXK_i^\dagger$ then its adjoint $\Psi^*:\mathcal{Y}\to\mathcal{X}$ has a Kraus representation $\Psi^*(Y)=\sum_iK_i^\dagger YK_i$, because
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Y,\Psi(X)\rangle&=\mathrm{tr}\left[Y^\dagger \left(\sum_iK_iXK_i^\dagger\right)\right]\tag1\\
&=\mathrm{tr}\left[\left(\sum_iK_i^\dagger Y^\dagger K_i\right)X\right]\tag2\\
&=\mathrm{tr}\left[\left(\sum_iK_i^\dagger YK_i\right)^\dagger X\right]\tag3\\
&=\langle\Psi^*(Y),X\rangle.\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, every channel with Hermitian or anti-Hermitian Kraus operators is self-adjoint. In particular, all Pauli channels including depolarizing channel are self-adjoint.